# Excel VBA query external .aspx page and retrieve data

Tags: asp.net, excel, vba

I've been struggling with this for about a day. Basically, I want to write an excel macro to loop through a list in excel, query a webpage and retrieve some data. Ideally I just want to retrieve the data I need so I can place it in an adjacent cell, but I'd do whatever it takes at this point.

The page is ASP.net, which I have no experience in; if it was .php I could probably manage, but I’m not even sure how to post to .aspx through javascript.

I can loop through my data just fine, and once I get the data I can write it to excel, so there are two parts I’m struggling with:

#### Part 1 – querying the webpage

[This is the page I want to query](http://www.ocpafl.org/searches/ParcelSearch.aspx). I need to search in `Property Address` and retrieve data from the results. The address I'll use for the example is `400 W Church St`. I thought it may be simple to submit a form like ".../ParcelSearch.aspx?name=...&value=...", but no dice.

#### Part 2 – grabbing the data

On the results, there is a table `DetailsSummary_Master` up top, with fieldsets that are defined with `<legend>` tags. I need the data in `<legend>Municipality</legend>`:
[image]

I can’t figure out what to do, loop through the `<td>`s? I thought maybe I could GetElementByID or maybe by tag, but I can’t seem to figure it out.

#### VBA

I used a few SO threads to try to figure it out so far. [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364172/how-to-automate-and-export-html-searchable-query-data-into-excel), [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209301/how-to-post-a-form-from-html-to-aspx-page) and [Third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816557/vba-access-remote-website-automate-clicking-submit-after-already-automating-cli), but I can't even seem to get it to POST properly. I'm keeping the subs separate for now.

This is what I have (stolen from the other thread) in regards to my problem:

```
Sub SubmitForm()

Dim objIE As Object
Dim xmlhttp As Object
Dim ieButton As Object
Dim strResponse As String
Dim strUrl As String
Dim strID As String
Dim strValue As String
Dim strSubmit As String

strID = "?name=ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentMain_ContentMain_ContentMain_ContentMain_TabContainer1_Searches_SubTabContainer1_QuickSearches_CompositAddressSearch1_AddressSearch1_ctl00_Address&value="
strValue = "400 W Church St"
strSubmit = strID & strValue


strUrl = "http://www.ocpafl.org/searches/ParcelSearch.aspx"
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.navigate "about:blank"
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

'~~> Indicates that page that will receive the request and the type of request being submitted
xmlhttp.Open "POST", "http://www.ocpafl.org/searches/ParcelSearch.aspx", False

'~~> Indicate that the body of the request contains form data
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

'~~> Send the data as name/value pairs
xmlhttp.Send "strSubmit"
strResponse = xmlhttp.responseText
objIE.navigate strUrl
objIE.Visible = True

Do While objIE.readystate <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

objIE.document.Write strResponse

Set xmlhttp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I don't actually need to run it through IE, I'd like to run it all hidden. I'm running this on Excel 2007 at work, but I have 2010 at home. We also have ridiculous IE8, so the less of that, the better. And I can loop or use an array, but I just can't seem to interface with the query. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe the line xmlhttp.Send "strsubmit" should omit the double-quotes on the variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For making the query, given the complexity of the form fields that the ASPX page is expecting on postback, you might find it easier to control the browser when making this call.  It will be rather slow, but it should work.

A fairly reliable tool for this is [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), and there are plugins to control [Selenium from Excel VBA](https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/).

**Edit:**  This Excel VBA code snippet should read out "Municipality Orlando".  You need to parameterize the below code and add cases for error conditions for your final version to query by any street address to get its municipality.  This should get you started though.  I used Selenium IDE with Firefox to generate the VBA code based on recording user actions, and then came up with an XPath query to grab the text.

```
  Dim selenium As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
  selenium.Start "firefox", "http://www.ocpafl.org/searches/ParcelSearch.aspx"
  selenium.setImplicitWait 5000

  selenium.setImplicitWait 5000
  selenium.Open "/searches/ParcelSearch.aspx"

  selenium.Click "id=popup_ok"
  selenium.Type "id=ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentMain_ContentMain_ContentMain_ContentMain_TabContainer1_Searches_SubTabContainer1_QuickSearches_CompositAddressSearch1_AddressSearch1_ctl00_Address", "400 W Church St"
  selenium.Click "id=ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentMain_ContentMain_ContentMain_ContentMain_TabContainer1_Searches_SubTabContainer1_QuickSearches_PropertyNameSearch1_ctl00"
  selenium.Click "id=ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentMain_ContentMain_ContentMain_ContentMain_TabContainer1_Searches_SubTabContainer1_QuickSearches_CompositAddressSearch1_AddressSearch1_ctl00_ActionButton1"
  Dim municipalityResult As String
  municipalityResult = selenium.getText("//fieldset[contains(legend,'Municipality')]")
  selenium.stop
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out. I don't have install rights at work, but I might be able to figure out a way.

Comment: I'm going to use your answer and request access to these tools. I think I'll `accept` it as well, even though it doesn't answer the question in the *way* that I wanted, it still answers my *particular question*. Thanks!